# When does looping through a list throw a Null Reference Exception?

Tags: c#, exception, nullreferenceexception

I haven't really done much exception handling before (fairly new to coding) and I'm unsure about where I need to catch exceptions and where there should be no exceptions to catch.

Specifically, I'm wondering about iterating through lists. Should I catch a Null Reference Exception everywhere that I loop through a list?

I'm thinking the answer is No since I have unit tests which test code that loops through a list and they do not throw an exception when the list has no elements.

So, I'm wondering. How do I know when I should catch a Null Reference Exception for looping through a list and when it is unnecessary?

Comment: only if the elements in list is set to null (e.g. its own life cycle makes that) you will get nullreferencesexcpetion.  if no elements and you trying to access a element it should throw outofbounds exception.

Comment: `NullReferenceException` should never be specifically caught, because it always indicates bug in the code.

Comment: You should only catch exceptions where you can specifically handle the exception and do something to address the problem. Don't catch exceptions that indicate bugs in the code, and don't catch exceptions that you can't do anything about. `NullReferenceException` and `OutOfMemoryException` are two exceptions that you should never catch, because you can't possibly handle them. Nor should you catch the generic `Exception`; always catch *specific* exception types. In general, the documentation will tell you which functions throw exceptions, and under what conditions those exceptions are thrown.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the feedback guys. That helps a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There will be no `NullReferenceException` if your list is empty. You can iterate over empty containers just fine.

If there is a chance that your container itself is `null` you should check this with a simple `if` before you loop. It might be a good practice to not let it become `null` in the first place though. Fail early in that case and throw an `ArgumentNullException` if you get a container that you expect to be not `null` instead of trying to come to terms with the fact that it *is* `null`.